# ¿Cómo hacer que no se impriman los logs en mi aplicación de envío de email?

Tags: java, email, xdebug

En mi aplicación se envían correos electrónicos pero se generan registros log y quiero que se quiten porque genera una cadena en b64 muy larga.

```
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;


import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger;

 public class LibEMAIL
  extends Observable

{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2830939533003598955L;
private final Log4JLogger logger = (Log4JLogger)LogFactory.getLog("com.jmfg.jmlibrerias.logging.utilerias");
  private String servidor;
  private String correo;
  private String usuario;
  private String passwd;
  private int puerto;
  private boolean conexionSegura;
  private boolean iniciarLogin;
  private boolean debug;
  private String mensajeAsunto;
  private String mensajeTexto;
  private ArrayList<String> mensajePara;
  private ArrayList<String> mensajeCC;
  private ArrayList<String> mensajeBCC;
  private byte[] attachmentByte;
  private String attachmentNombre;
  private String pathArchivo;
  private String nombreDocumento;


  public LibEMAIL() {}

  public LibEMAIL(String servidor, String correo, String usuario, String passwd, int puerto, boolean conexionSegura, boolean iniciarLogin, boolean debug,String pathArchivo)
  {
    this.servidor = servidor;
    this.correo = correo;
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.passwd = passwd;
    this.puerto = puerto;
    this.conexionSegura = conexionSegura;
    this.iniciarLogin = iniciarLogin;
    this.debug = debug;
    this.pathArchivo=pathArchivo;    

  }

  public boolean enviarEmail(ArrayList<String> listado, String asunto, String texto, String nombreDocumento)
  {
    return enviarEmail(listado, null, null, asunto, texto, null, null, nombreDocumento);
  }

//  public void enviarEmail(ArrayList<String> listado, String asunto, String texto, byte[] attByte, String attName, String nombreDocumento)
//  {
//    enviarEmail(listado, null, null, asunto, texto, attByte, attName, nombreDocumento);
//  }

  public boolean enviarEmail(ArrayList<String> listado, ArrayList<String> listadocc, ArrayList<String> listadobcc, String asunto, String texto, byte[] att, String attName, String nombreDocumento)
  {
    this.mensajePara = listado;
    this.mensajeCC = listadocc;
    this.mensajeBCC = listadobcc;
    this.mensajeAsunto = asunto;
    this.mensajeTexto = texto;
    this.attachmentByte = att;
    this.attachmentNombre = attName;
    this.nombreDocumento = nombreDocumento;




    return envE();
  }

  public boolean envE()
  {

    String protocol = this.conexionSegura ? "smtps" : "smtp";

    JavaMailSenderImpl sender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    sender.setHost(this.servidor);
    sender.setPort(this.puerto);
    sender.setProtocol(protocol);
    if (this.iniciarLogin)
    {
      sender.setUsername(this.usuario);



      sender.setPassword(this.passwd);
    }
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap)CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);

    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.setProperty("mail.debug", Boolean.toString(this.debug));//CRIS LE CAMBIE LINEA ORIGINAL   props.setProperty("mail.debug", Boolean.toString(this.debug));
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".user", this.usuario);
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".host", this.servidor);
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".port", Integer.toString(this.puerto));
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".connectiontimeout", "30000");
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".timeout", "30000");
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".from", this.correo);
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".auth", Boolean.toString(this.iniciarLogin));
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".ssl.enable", Boolean.toString(this.conexionSegura));
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".ssl.checkserveridentity", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail." + protocol + ".ssl.trust", "*");


    sender.setJavaMailProperties(props);
```

Answer (score 2):

prueba dejando la propiedad debug como falso,

```
props.setProperty("mail.debug", false);
```

y para el comportamiento de JavaMailSenderImpl puedes encontrar la documentacion completa aqui:
  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html